How does Krylov Schur handle repeated eigenvalues?
I am trying to implement krylov-schur based on this document, algorithm 3.
Which refers to this description of the arnoldi with deflation method, in algorithm 2.
I am lost because the arnoldi method is trying to do a QR iterations approximation of the eigenvalues. So take the identity matrix $I$.
The arnoldi method is trying to compute an orthonormal basis for the krylov space $\{v, Av, A^2v, A^3v, \cdots\}$. If $A$ is the identity matrix, then that space is linearly dependent (trivially). So the basis is technically just $v$. However, my expectation is that, for an eigenvalue of 1 with multiplicity n, the resulting eigenvectors should span $\mathbb{R}^n$ .
The high level description of the method I shared doesn't seem to explain what to do in cases of higher multiplicities.
